# Низкоуровневый интерфейс

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Почему данный интерфейс называется низкоуровневым?
https://jquery-docs.ru/category/ajax/low-level-interface/

Comment: Потому что есть jQeury.get и jQuery.post, которые базируются на на низкоуровневом интерфейсе.

Answer (score 1):

В jQuery существует официальное деление всех ajax методов на две группы:

- **Низкоуровневый ajax интерфейс**

  - jQuery.ajax()
  - jQuery.ajaxSetup()
  - jQuery.ajaxPrefilter()
  - jQuery.ajaxTransport()
- **Высокоуровневый ajax интерфейс (упрощенные ajax методы)**

  - load(url, data, callback)
  - jQuery.get(url, data, callback, type)
  - jQuery.getJSON(url, data, callback)
  - jQuery.getScript(url, callback)
  - jQuery.post(url, data, callback, type)

Основное отличие низкоуровневых методов ajax от высокоуровневых в том что они предоставляют больше возможностей при работе с ajax.